# Adding record with new foreign key

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have few tables to store company information in my database, but I want to focus on two of them. One table, `Company`, contains `CompanyID`, which is autoincremented, and some other columns that are irrelevant for now. The problem is that companies use different versions of names (e.g. IBM vs. International Business Machines) and I want/need to store them all for futher use, so I can't keep names in `Company` table. Therefore I have another table, `CompanyName` that uses `CompanyID` as a foreign key (it's one-to-many relation).

Now, I need to import some new companies, and I have names only. Therefore I want to add them to `CompanyName` table, but create new records in `Company` table immediately, so I can put right `CompanyID` in `CompanyName` table.

Is it possible with one query? How to approach this problem properly? Do I need to go as far as writing VBA procedure to add records one by one?

I searched Stack and other websites, but I didn't find any solution for my problem, and I can't figure it out myself. I guess it could be done with form and subform, but ultimately I want to put all my queries in macro, so data import would be done automatically.

I'm not database expert, so maybe I just designed it badly, but I didn't figure out another way to cleanly store multiple names of the same entity.

Comment: How is your _companies ready to be imported list_ set out? Are they all separate companies, or are there items that are the same company (as in your IBM example)?  Is there anything in the new list that links the company with two names together?

Comment: Not really. The problem is that people who enter data into system make mess sometimes. They don't check if company exists and just add new record. It happens that names are similar (e.g. Company vs. Company, Inc), but there's no rule.

For now I'm going to create a record in Company table, take it's ID, then use in CompanyName table. Rinse and repeat for all missing records, maybe in a single transaction to keep things safe.

Answer (score 0):

The table structure you setup appears to be a good way to do this.  But there's not a way to insert records into both tables at the same time.  One option is to write two queries to insert records into Company and then CompanyName.  After inserting records into Company you will need to create a query that joins from the source table to the Company table joining it on a field that uniquely defines the record beside the autoincrement key.  That will allow you to get the key field from Company for use when you insert into CompanyName.

The other option, is to write some VBA code to loop through the source data inserting records into both.  The would be preferable since it should be more reliable.

Comment: It doesn't sound promising :( I didn't mention I don't have any column in `Company` table I could use to join. Even though it's central table representing company itself, it serves mainly as a foreign keys source, due to inconsistency of data I have to work on. There are few more tables that work in similar manner, but they do not change anything in my question.